# Case-insensitive string matching in LINQ Where

Tags: c#, lambda

I was working on something that required me to catch the first char of a string. and return if it starts with S or s.

The pseudocode I considered was:

```
var foodsWithS = Foods.Where(food => food.Name[0] == 'S' || food.Name[0] == "s").Select(i => i.Name);
```

Unfortunately, this fails. What would be the best way to do this? Currently I have two lambdas to check for each case of the letter.

Comment: ^ In particular [the second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/444818/1324033)

Comment: Your pseudocode was close, but as @Jace's answer points out, `StartsWith` is the right way to do this (assuming you're using LINQ-to-Objects).

Comment: true . quite similar ... but good to see it in a LAMBDA expression

Answer (score 4):

`foods.Where(x => x.StartsWith("S", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a collection of string objects, You can also use StartsWith;

```
food.StartsWith("s", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```